# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer get file content

Tags: php, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I need to attach an XLS-file to e-mail via PHP.
The Problem is - `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer` send a HTTP Header to a browser an then the content. `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer` API has no any functions like `get_content` to become the file content directly. I don't want to save the file first, I just want to jump this step over, saving the content directly as attachment.
Any ideas?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a "write to file" method in Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer. At most you can send it directly to the client with the `->send()` method. This means you COULD capture the output with PHP's [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start), and grab the data as a string, which can then be inserted into an email (e.g. via PHPMailer's `->AddStringAttachment()`).

You may want to investigate switching to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), since Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is essentially dead in the water, minus a few minor bug fixes. PHPExcel supports Excel 2007, while S_E_W is stuck at Excel 5.0 (early 90's). It also has a `->save()` method to write to file.

Comment: the file i generate with PEAR-Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3...is in Read-Only Mode, Any idea to solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

ob_start();

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->setVersion(8, 'utf-8');
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('sheet 1');
$worksheet->setInputEncoding('utf-8');

$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'test');
$worksheet->write(1, 0, 'test2');

$workbook->close();

$sXls = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Albeit the OP doesn't want to save the file first, I was looking for a means to output inline as opposed to attachment using the `::send` method.

The PEAR `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer` `0.1` to `0.9.4` constructor supports a `$filename` argument. [[sic 0.1]](https://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/docs/0.1/__filesource/fsource_Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer__Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.1Writer.php.html#a52) 
 and [[sic 0.9.4]](https://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/docs/0.9.4/__filesource/fsource_Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer__Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.4SpreadsheetExcelWriter.php.html#a54)

When supplied, calling the `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer::close` method on the instantiated object, will output the generated spreadsheet to the specified path.

```
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('/path/to/output/file.xls');
//...
$workbook->close();

$data = file_get_contents('/path/to/output/file.xls'); 
//or file_get_contents($workbook->_filename);
unlink('/path/to/output/file.xls');
```